how to fix libertine package with lualatex putting tilde too low?
When I try to use the libertine package with lualatex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
  \(\mathbf{\tilde{n}}\)
\end{document}

I'm seeing problems making a letter with a tilde above it bold:

It looks ok without the libertine package or without being bold. Is this a known issue with lualatex or something I can fix?
[update]: Here's longer list of n's and ñ's. The hope would be that the boldness of the n matches regular text bold. And that the tildes all end up in a reasonable place. I'm not sure what to expect for differences between mathbf/symbf but for various attempts they look different:
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{libertine}
% Supports symbf
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}
  
  \textbf{n}
  \textbf{ñ} % U+00F1
  \textbf{ñ} % U+006E U+0303
  \(\mathbf{ñ}\) % U+00F1
  \(\mathbf{ñ}\) % U+006E U+0303
  \(\mathbf{\tilde{n}} \)
  \(\symbf{ñ}\) % U+00F1
  \(\symbf{ñ}\) % U+006E U+0303
  \(\symbf{\tilde{n}}\)

\end{document}

With libertinus this outputs:


\mathbf{ñ} seems to work.

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}. Or configure maths for unicode?

@Marijn interesting. So ñ (U+00F1) works. but ñ (U+006E U+0303) does not.

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec} didn't seem to work. What do you mean by configure maths for unicode?

@AlecJacobson Hi. Do you have try with libertinus-otf? https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/libertinus-otf/doc/libertinus-otf-doc.pdf

@Sebastiano libertinus gives a different wrong result.

@cfr Hi. Yes, I have seen on my laptop compiling with lualatex the code of the user.

@AlecJacobson Put the line before loading libertine. The result at least puts the accent in the correct place. On unicode, I meant using unicode-math, but libertinus maths doesn't work ....

@Sebastiano Do you get a correct result? Because I tried with both libertinus and libertinus-otf and the accent is always misplaced.

@cfr Yes you're right. But to the minimal working examples of egreg work always :-)

@Sebastiano I'm pretty sure TeX has an \if@user@egreg ... somewhere ....

@cfr Sure

Don't use libertine. The font is long unsupported.
Use libertinus instead, and \symbf instead of \mathbf.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

\(\tilde{\symbf{n}}+a+b\)

\(\symbf{\tilde{n}}+a+b\)

\end{document}

In my opinion the first syntax is correct.


Could you explain why/when \symbf versus \mathbf?

I'm also curious. Meanwhile, the \symbf bold n is every so slightly less bold than \textbf{n} or \mathbf{n}.

@AlecJacobson \usepackage[semibold]{libertinus}

@cfr do a copy & paste to see the difference between \symbf + \mathbf: the first copy the n as U+1D427 (mathematical bold small n) and so as mathematical symbol, while the second copies it simply as U+006E (latin small n).

@UlrikeFischer Do you mean from the PDF? Because they both copy-paste as n. Or what am I meant to paste them into? They actually look different in the PDF, but they paste identically. Paste: nn or do I have to compile with something other than LuaTeX to see a difference? I also tried pasting into my editor and onto the commandline: echo 'nn' | sed 's/n/x/g' -> xx where the echo is pasted from the PDF and the sed expression is entered normally.

@UlrikeFischer Actually, I don't think where I paste it matters. They're identical as copied to the clipboard ....

@cfr Then your pdf reader is changing something. They have clearly different tounicode values in the pdf

@UlrikeFischer Yes, I realise that. As I say, they also look different in the PDF. They are clearly different glyphs. (I guess theoretically that's compatible with them having the same meaning, but that's not relevant here.) It's just that I can't tell the difference by copy-pasting. Short of taking the PDF apart, is there some other way of distinguishing them? I guess this must be a fairly common thing on Linux since my PDF viewer is a pretty standard one.

Dumb question: both libertinus-type1 and libertine are by Bob Tennent, and the latter has a doc dates April 2024, while the former December 2020. In what sense is then libertine unsupported? (I am not being polemic, it's a honest question! I've been using libertine with libertinust1math for years and never had a problem.)

@campa The fonts themselves are no longer developed. The package is just an interface for usage in LaTeX.

If you must continue to use the libertine package, I suggest you write either \tilde{\mathbf{n}} or \textbf{\~{n}} in math mode.
I have a hunch that \tilde{\mathbf{n}} is what you want.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine} % or: '\usepackage{libertinus}'
\begin{document}

$\mathbf{\tilde{n}}$ 
$\tilde{\mathbf{n}}$ 
$\textbf{\~{n}}$

\end{document}

